# Prices and returns

Tags: option-pricing, returns, payoff

I want to convert the payoff of an Asian and a lookback Call option with prices in their corresponding with returns. Example: for an European Call $\varphi(S_T)=(S_T-K)^+$, so knowing that $S_T=S_0(1+r_t)^T=S_0\prod_{i=1}^{T}(1+r_i)=S_0R_T$ I can write that $(S_T-K)^+=(S_0R_T-K)^+$.

If an Asian Call payoff is $\varphi(S_T)=(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}S_t-K)^+$ and a lookback Call payoff is $\varphi(S_T)=(S_{\operatorname{max}}-K)^+$, how do I obtain respectively

- $(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}S_t-K)^+=(\frac{S_0}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}R_t-K)^+$,
- $(S_{\operatorname{max}}-K)^+=(S_0R_{\operatorname{max}}-K)^+$ for $R_{\operatorname{max}}:=\underset{1 \leq t \leq T}{\operatorname{max}}\begin{Bmatrix}
  R_t
  \end{Bmatrix}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with **"how do I obtain respectively"**: What do you want to obtain? A pricing formula or payoff formula? That would be helpful. In any case, it is most often quite helpful to transform to log-returns, i.e. $S_T=S_0e^{x_T}$.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Thanks for your answer! I have to verify, mathematically, the equalities to in points 1 and 2, but I couldn't do it until now. PS: I know that is more helpful using log-returns $\operatorname{log}(\frac{S_{t+1}}{S_t})=\operatorname{log}(1+r_t)$ but the author of book, to prove the equality in the example for European options, uses the compound interest regime and not that continuos.

Comment: Note that, your return at time $t$ is basically defined by $\frac{S_t}{S_0}$. Then the conversion is straightforward.

Comment: @Gordon Omg... I was getting lost in a glass of water. Thanks!